# How to avoid the white screen before first activity is shown?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-theme

When opening my app for the first time, I can see a white screen for two or three seconds. After that, the first activity is shown.

How to avoid this annoying white screen? I'm pretty sure it's caused by the theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` which I'm using.

I'm using this new theme because I'm using a NavigationView with a PagerTitleStrip and in the documentation of Google they where using this theme to develop this kind of views.

How can I avoid that annoying white screen? If that screen can be for example black, it is much better and much less annoying. Can its color be changed? Has this theme a black version but without losing compatibility with a NavigationView with a PagerTitleStrip?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: There is a dark theme, but you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't find Theme.AppCompat.Dark.DarkActionBar ¿can you find it?

Comment: You would appear to be tying up the main application thread, preventing it from rendering your UI. Enable `StrictMode` to complain about any disk or network I/O that you are doing on the main application thread. Beyond that, use method tracing with your IDE to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok i will try it but please, can you tell me if there is a "Dark" alternative to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar which respects compatibility with NavigationView with a PagerTitleStrip?

Comment: There is no `Theme.AppCompat.Dark`. It's just `Theme.AppCompat`. Remove the `.Light`

Comment: @cricket_007 are you sure? tryed it and error: Error:(515) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: I didn't say keep the action bar part of the theme name. There is a Theme Editor window in Android Studio that you are welcome to view all the possible theme options

Comment: @CommonsWare I added a simple splash screen which does nothing and i have the same lag time before splash screen is showed. How is this possible? Maybe too munch dependencies in gradle file?

Comment: "How is this possible?" -- I have no idea. Use method tracing with your IDE to determine where you are spending your time.

Answer (score 0):

On your xml that you are using for your splashscreen add

```
android:opacity="opaque"
```

Comment: I'm not using a splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

As cricket_007 tell in the comments, it is possible to get black color theme instead of Light simply using "Theme.AppCompat"

Also as CommonsWare says in the comments, it is a good practice to search if you are doing too much work in the main thread and use threads to get a fast UI load.